# Layout of table contents

Tags: arrays

I would like to arrange the information when only s1, s2 and p1, p2, p3 as shown attached image. That is, consider an unbalanced situation.
We can easily achieve when s1, s2, s3 and c1, c2, c3 exist (balanced):

```
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
s_1: p_2 \succ p_3 \succ p_1 \succ \emptyset& \quad &
p_1: s_1 \succ s_2 \succ s_3 \succ \emptyset\\
s_2: p_3 \succ p_1 \succ p_2 \succ \emptyset& \quad &
p_2: s_2 \succ s_3 \succ s_1 \succ \emptyset\\
s_3: p_1 \succ p_2 \succ p_3 \succ \emptyset& \quad &
p_3: s_3 \succ s_1 \succ s_2 \succ \emptyset\\
\end{array}
```

How can I achieve for unbalanced one like the following image?
[image]

Comment: What is the `¥` symbol?

Comment: Explain in a better way what you want to achieve. What is an unbalanced situation, what do you want to change by excluding s3, and so on. Swap ¥ against \ in your example.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
  \[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      s_{1} : p_{2} \succ p_{3} \succ p_{1} \succ \emptyset \quad & 
      p_{1} : s_{1} \succ s_{2} \succ s_{3} \succ \emptyset\\
      s_{2} : p_{3} \succ p_{1} \succ p_{2} \succ \emptyset \quad & 
      p_{2} : s_{2} \succ s_{3} \succ s_{1} \succ \emptyset\\
      ~  \quad & 
      p_{3} : s_{3} \succ s_{1} \succ s_{2} \succ \emptyset\\
 \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

[image: pic]

```
\[
    \begin{array}{c}
      s_{1} : p_{2} \succ p_{3} \succ p_{1} \succ \emptyset \quad \\
      s_{2} : p_{3} \succ p_{1} \succ p_{2} \succ \emptyset \quad
    \end{array}
    \begin{array}{c}
      p_{1} : s_{1} \succ s_{2} \succ s_{3} \succ \emptyset\\
      p_{2} : s_{2} \succ s_{3} \succ s_{1} \succ \emptyset\\
      p_{3} : s_{3} \succ s_{1} \succ s_{2} \succ \emptyset
    \end{array}
\]
```

Comment: Thank you for this! But I would like to put  s1 and s2 on center like my edited image.